# Specific column names for specific items

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, list, column

I wonder if I could have specific column names for specific items in my list.

This is what I have:
I have a list of software tools. But each software requires different things. When displaying the list I want to show just basic columns like version, operating system, etc. But when I click on the item I'd like to show in this form specific columns which just fit to this special item.

Could I do this with views again? If yes how?

Or do I have to play around with JSLink/CSR to show specific columns if the item name is XYZ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work with different content types here. Each content type can contain a different set of columns that are shown in the corresponding views.

[Introduction to Content Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms472236(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks! Found another [link](http://en.share-gate.com/blog/sharepoint-content-types-understand-use-create) for detailed information about **Content Type**.

Answer (score 0):

You can create different content types for each software tools and add specific columns to those content types.

The requirement specified by you, is achievable using combination of content types and columns. So there is no need to go for CSR options.